# Question on CSS floated child div

Tags: css, html, css-float

I was playing around with a floated div example, where I have a floated container and some floated child divs except one non-floated child

You can see the example on;

http://jsfiddle.net/emeRJ/7/

Now I wanted to understand the behavior or rendering for this non-floated child div...

2 questions:

1. Could you please explain how it renders currently and what difference does it make if I have it coded after all the child divs (i.e. it is the last child element)
2. Also will it have any impact on the non-floated child if I make the container as overflow:hidden ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer 1

At the moment the un-floated `div` right at the top with the red border is displaying `block` so it spans the whole width of it's containing `div`. It is unaffected by the other `divs` in the containing element

If you move it to the last position in the containing `div` the other floated `divs` do affect the un-floated one so you need to `clear: both;` (which clears the float and places the un-floated `div` under the floated `divs`) with `CSS`, otherwise any text contained within the un-floated one will be floated to the left and then would proceed to wrap around the floated elements (it doesn't do this at the moment because the text isn't long enough). Unless that's what you are trying to achieve?

Answer 2

It shouldn't make any difference as nothing is actually overflowing the containing `div` which would be set to `overflow: hidden;`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thx a lot for the answer...But it would be really great if you could provide the details in more simpler terms so that I am able to understand...also there are 2 separate parts/ques..

Comment: This is a quite concise explanation of what happens in this particular example... If you're having trouble understanding how floats work you might want to read [this article](http://phrogz.net/css/understandingfloats.html) for some more in-depth explanation.